# bypassing Internet Explorer options for protected mode using Selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I tried different methods/ways to set my internet options setting using regedit but it was not modifying my internet explorer options to protected mode. I searched in the internet on how to address the issue on using IEDriver that needs a configuration to be either protected/non-protected on all zones using the path below: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\

can anyone point me to the right direction? (i have limited access that is why i cannot change the settings using the internet options from the browser itself).

thanks again for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are doing the testing for someone, but have limited access, please ask for more. You need to control your environment for testing. If they don't give you enough permission, I'd suggest "strike" (not a real one, obviously). Workaround is possible, but highly discouraged. [Read developer's article](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.nz/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html)

Comment: i have created a selenium script for testing our web application. I actually tried that suggestion in that article but it is not working. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you on a work computer? If so, it is likely your corporate internet settings are overwriting your local settings. **Try the following:**

1. Go to regedit
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones
3. In 1, 2, 3, 4 you will find the Reg file "2500" in each folder
4. Go through each of these folders, edit 2500 and change it to the same value in each 1, 2, 3, 4, either true or false is fine as long as they're the same
5. Try running your script!

**If that doesn't work:**
Recheck those registry values after editing them. Are they changing back to their previous value even after you have changed them? If so, then it means your corporate policy is going to keep changing it back.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [This Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242503/how-do-i-avoid-issues-with-protected-mode-using-iedriverserver-in-selenium). You may also have to make your changes under HKLM to get it to work.